# How to create a button toggle with two states, that behaves like a checkbox for form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap buttons (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) to create a checkbox-like input, with two states:

- One that displays a button with "Option A selected"; and
- The other that displays "Option B selected".

When the button is clicked, I want it to toggle between these two messages, but also be able to pass the selection to the form.

What's the best way to do this? My first thought was to try and mark-up `data-toggle="button"`, but I'm not convinced this is the easiest way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/p9AaY/)

```
<button id="switch" class="on"></button>
<span></span>

$('#switch').click(function() {

    $(this).val('100'); // Set the value of your choice

    if($(this).hasClass('on')) {
       $(this).toggleClass('off','on');
       $('span').text('Option A Selected and value is '+$(this).val());
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('off')) {
       $(this).val('200'); // Set the value of your choice
       $('span').text('Option B Selected and value is '+$(this).val());
    }        

});
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/p9AaY/) is updated and of course you can set the button background according to your wish.